# Failed to create Blob container in Microsoft Azure

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I followed the tutorial of Azure Blob storage service [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java) and supplied the connection string from my storage account to create a container but it did not work as the container is not created and the application runs until I terminate it manually. I used azure-blob-storage API version 12.4.0.

Here is the code:

```
// Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();

//Create a unique name for the container
String containerName = "quickstartblobs" + java.util.UUID.randomUUID();

// Create the container and return a container client object
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.createBlobContainer(containerName);
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>aaaa</groupId>
    <artifactId>ddada</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.327</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-storage -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.108.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.hpi.cloudraid</groupId>
            <artifactId>erasure</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hiramsoft.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsalparser</artifactId>
            <version>0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.googlejavaformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-java-format</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.crypto.tink</groupId>
            <artifactId>tink</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-rc3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.morphia.morphia</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0.rc1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0.rc1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hierynomus</groupId>
            <artifactId>sshj</artifactId>
            <version>0.27.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-blob -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
            <version>12.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

It also showed another error message like this:

```
May 29, 2020 3:39:49 PM io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext invokeExceptionCaught
WARNING: An exception 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpUtil.formatHostnameForHttp(java.net.InetSocketAddress)'' [enable DEBUG level for full stacktrace] was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpUtil.formatHostnameForHttp(java.net.InetSocketAddress)'
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpClientHandler.resolveHostHeaderValue(HttpClientConnect.java:593)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpClientHandler.requestWithBody(HttpClientConnect.java:552)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.lambda$onStateChange$0(HttpClientConnect.java:429)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:430)
    at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:473)
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onStateChange(PooledConnectionProvider.java:525)
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onStateChange(PooledConnectionProvider.java:434)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelActive(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:62)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:213)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:199)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:192)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:414)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelActive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelActive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:213)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:213)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:199)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:192)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler.userEventTriggered(SslProvider.java:731)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:329)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:315)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeSuccess(SslHandler.java:1480)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1318)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1170)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1195)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:138)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Any reasons why it did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Thanks to Ihsan Haikal for sharing. If anyone who faces similar problems cannot create a container using the following method, please check the content of pom.xml The problem should not be the code but the configuration part.

**Original Answer:**

With this steps I can create container on my storage:

First, import:

```
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
```

And this is the code in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>12.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Second, use code:

```
// Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net").buildClient();

//Create a unique name for the container
String containerName = "quickstartblobs";

// Create the container and return a container client object
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.createBlobContainer(containerName);
```

You should get connection string from this place:

[image]

Then, it creates the container:

[image]

You can check what different between you and me.:)